# AngularJS : Error message not get printed

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the error message on my form whenever the student name is not available.

so i tried this code

```
<form name="studentForm" novalidate
            data-ng-submit="studentForm.$valid && enterStudentRecord()">

            <div>Student Name :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="studentName" required> <span data-ng-show="studentForm.studentName.$touched && studentForm.studentName.$invalid">The name is required.</span><br>
            <div>Street :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="street"><br>
            <div>City :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="city"><br>
            <div>State :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="state"><br>
            <div>zipcode :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="zipcode"><br> <br> <br>
            <button type="submit">Add Student Record</button>
        </form>
```

now when i click on submit button without enter any value in student name i am not getting the errormessage.

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

You should create name for input

```
 <input data-ng-model="studentName"  name ="studentName" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add `name` attribute `name="studentName"` in the element to perform the validations.
- Set a variable on click `event` into submit button and get that variable while displaying the message.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="studentForm" novalidate data-ng-submit="studentForm.$valid && enterStudentRecord()">
            <div>Student Name :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="studentName" name="studentName" required> 
            <span data-ng-show="submitted == true && studentForm.studentName.$error.required">The name is required.</span><br>
            <div>Street :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="street"><br>
            <div>City :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="city"><br>
            <div>State :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="state"><br>
            <div>zipcode :</div>
            <input data-ng-model="zipcode"><br> <br> <br>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">Add Student Record</button>
        </form>
</div>
```